# How to Generate Gradlew on to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, flutter, continuous-deployment, gradlew

How to generate gradlew file to Jenkins Android Project? My project is not Android Native. My project is Flutter.

I try to create CD with Jenkins and I got some errors.

this is my pipeline code (JenkinsFile)

```
stage('Build Release APK') {
    sh "ls ./android"
    sh "./android/gradlew clean assembleRelease"
}
```

ls output is,(There is not `gradlew` file)

```
ls ./android
app
build.gradle
gradle
gradle.properties
key.properties
settings.gradle
```

This is an error I got

```
./android/gradlew clean assembleRelease
/Users/donperera/.jenkins/workspace/demo@tmp/durable-b0592b49/script.sh: line 1: ./android/gradlew: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to build apk/aap with Jenkins?

Is it possible to use this plugin? but I already added this one. But not in this my script. https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-jenkins/

Answer (score 6):

`gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` is an executable of Gradle that can be used to execute **gradle** commands.

> `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` uses `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` file for execution.

So there are 3 files in play:

- `gradlew` for **mac** and **linux**
- `gradlew.bat` for **windows**
- `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`

The thing here is, these files already exists when you create your **flutter** project. But these files are **ignored** by `.gitignore` of the project by default. so these files won't be available in your **CI/CD** server.

#### METHOD 1 [RECOMMENDED]

You don't need them to build your project when it is a flutter project. You need flutter SDK to be installed. You can use flutter SDK to build your project. Use following command for release build [you might need to set flutter SDK for your **Jenkins** server]:

```sh
flutter build apk --release
```

It will run `assembleRelease` internally and will generate your APK file.

#### METHOD 2 [NOT RECOMMENDED]

If you want to do it your way then you can add those 3 files to version control by removing their references from `.gitignore` file and push it to your repository. Then you'll have those file in your **Jenkins** workspace. You'll have to grant execution permissions to `gradlew` if you are on **mac** or **linux** which can be done by following command.

```sh
chmod +x ./gradlew
```

then you can use following command to build your app:

```sh
./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

> **NOTICE:** Method 2 is not recommended because when you run flutter commands, it sets some properties to gradle from `pubspec.yaml` file like `version name`, `version code`. So if you made changes to `pubspec.yaml` file and haven't run flutter command after that, then running `gradlew` directly won't include those changes. In this case, your apk might built with older version or might not even built as it reads version info from `local.properties` file which is auto-modified by flutter commands and it is excluded by default from version control. So, you'll also have to add `local.properties` file by removing its reference from `.gitignore` file which is very very dirty because it has location reference of android SDK and your server might not have android SDK on that location. Again you need to tackle that. so don't use this method.

Comment: method 1: I already tried. ```sh "/Users/donperera/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter build apk --split-per-abi"```  Error is ```bash: /Users/docperera/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: Operation not permitted```

Comment: method 2: I tried it now. Error is ```chmod +x ./android/gradlew clean assembleRelease
chmod: ./android/gradlew: No such file or directory
chmod: clean: No such file or directory
chmod: assembleRelease: No such file or directory```

Comment: @BloodLoss yes, it is possible to fix error in method 1

Comment: @BloodLoss you have to run `chmod +x ./android/gradlew`. Not `chmod +x ./android/gradlew clean assembleRelease`

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Is it release apk without `clean assembleRelease`?

Comment: @BloodLoss I haven't faced this but I think this might help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41486

Comment: thanks for helping..Just to know, what is the best cicd for mobile apps?(both android and ios)..now I used jenkins but lots of error I faced

Comment: `chmod +x ./android/gradlew` command permits `gradlew` to be executable. `./android/gradlew clean assembleRelease` generates the build. @BloodLoss

Comment: @BloodLoss Jenkins is not suitable for beginners as it requires a lot of manual configurations. You can try code-magic for flutter. There also others like Bit-Rise, Travis, CircleCI, etc. You should try that. Bit-rise and code-magic are easy and you can find tutorials on them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207586/discussion-between-bloodloss-and-birju-vachhani).

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that "on Jenkins". You should do that in your codebase. Execute the wrapper command (`gradle wrapper`), add wrapper files to Git, commit and push.

Comment: I installed `gradle` and run `gradle wrapper` then I build Jenkins. Same error is coming